# How to derive this equation in many ways?

Tags: calculus, differential

Given the equation:
$$y=\sin^4(x)\cdot\cos^4(x)$$
I have derived the equation using product rule:
$$f'(x)\cdot g(x)+f(x)\cdot g'(x)$$
Then I`ve got $$y'=4\sin^3(x)\cos^5(x)-4\sin^5(x)\cos^3(x)$$, then factoring my final is $$y'=4\sin^3(x)\cos^3(x)[1-2\sin^2(x)]$$.
How about using identities before deriving? Does it give the same answer since there are many identities we can substitute from.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is.  Yes, you can use trigonometric identities to find the derivative of this function in many different forms.  Which form do you want?

Comment: "Does it give the same answer": no need to try to guarantee a yes. Calculus is an exact science.

Comment: Using the sin^2(x)=[1-cos(2x)]/2 and for cos^2(x)=[1+cos(2x)]/2

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A,\cos2B=2\cos^2B-1=1-2\sin^2B, $

$$16y=(2\sin x\cos x)^4=\sin^42x$$

$$64y=(2\sin^22x)^2=(1-\cos4x)^2=1-2\cos4x+\cos^24x$$

$$128y=2-4\cos4x+(1+\cos8x)$$